# Compute sets of size n given an array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, permutation

I'm not sure if my question title makes sense or even if I completely know what I'm trying to get at, but say you are given some letters in an array, and a number n:

```
char[] arr = ['a','b'], n = 4

How can you compute all the permutations of size n?

aaaa
bbbb
abab
bbaa
aabb
... (and so on)
```

I can't figure out how to do this and would really appreciate some help. I guess why I'm confused is because the size you want to make (4) is greater than the number of elements in your array and I haven't seen that before.

Comment: permutations count = array.length^n. For your example it's 2^4=16

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem could be to create a recursive method that makes all permutations in the set (in this case a and b) and call it n times to form a string.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code...

Recursive function that accepts a String parameter:

- if the length is 4, add string to results
- otherwise, loop over chars:

  - recursively call function with param + char

Start by calling function with a blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the question in a different way, say you are given `n` boxes, in every box you need to put a letter selected from array `arr`, since every letter in the array can be used more than once, so for every box you have as many choices as `arr.length`, to group all the boxes together, you'll have a total of `arr.length ^ n` permutations, a simple working example in java using recursion:

```
public class Test {

    static List<String> res;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        char[] arr = {'a','b'};
        int n = 4;

        res = new ArrayList<>();
        permutate(arr, new char[n], n, 0);

        System.out.println("size = " + res.size());
        System.out.println("permutations = " + Arrays.toString(res.toArray()));
    }

    static void permutate(char[] arr, char[] permutation, int n ,int idx){
        if(idx == n){
            res.add(new String(permutation));
            return;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            permutation[idx] = arr[i];
            permutate(arr, permutation, n, idx + 1);
        }
    }

}
```